# How to allow user's to access specific controller as a guest in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm working on a Yii base project, and i have a search controller which i want to allow access for all users both logged in and a guest user. I don't need a user to login before they can search items so i want to exempt this controller because when i try to access this controller i was redirected to login page.

my controller is below

```
    class SearchController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

     public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['index'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],

        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {

        $params = 'product_id,title, price,unit_sold,state,city,profile_img,store_name,item_number,slug';
        $model= Products::find()->select($params)->asArray()->all();

        //print_r($model); exit;
        //check if model has value and loop through the value else set the value to empty array
        //to avoid throwing  undefine error
        if(isset($model) && !empty($model)){
            foreach($model as $v){
           $data[] = $v;
          }
        }else{
           $data[] = []; 
        }

        return $this->render('index',[
            'data' => $data,
        ]);

    }

}
```

and the route is `http//www.mysite.com/search/index`, after i visit the route as anonymous user i get redirected to `http//www.mysite.com/site/login`

Note: Initially the behaviours method was not there i added this as a fix to this problem but till i get redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Yii2 AccessControl](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol)

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

If you used [mdmsoft/yii2-admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin) then add below code to `config/web.php`

```
use mdm\admin\components\AccessControl;

return [
   'components' => [
       'as access' => [
           'class' => AccessControl::class,
           'allowActions' => [
                 'search/index',
            ],
       ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: thanks for your help i tried your solution now but still get redirected to login page

Comment: still no luck i added 'as access' => [
           'class' => AccessControl::class,
           'allowActions' => [
                 'search/index',
            ],
       ],    in the conponents part of my app but got an error that AccessControl::class was not found so i changed AccessControl::class to AccessControl::className and still get the same error finally i changed it to AccessControl::className() and nothing showed up just a blank page but i can acess this page without error if i login as a user, any other ways of solving this??

Comment: @ vishuB thanks for your help, i got it working already, i followed your updated answer and i modify the part 'class' => AccessControll::class to point to directory where access control is located in my app like 'class' => 'mdm\admin\components\AccessControl',  and it works perfect, thanks i will accept your answer

Comment: @ vishuB oh so how do i upvote am not really used to stackoverflow